# Super simple MVC question, how does it know what the ID is of an object you're editing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Having trouble grasping this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Movie movieToEdit)
{

    var originalMovie = (from m in _db.MovieSet
                         where m.Id == movieToEdit.Id
                         select m).First();
```

In this case you've posted your form, and it gets the movie you're going to edit by checking movieToEdit.Id

However I don't understand how it knows what the Id is. I thought that movieToEdit was created by examining the View. The fields on the View are only:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <p>
        <label for="Title">Title:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("Title", Model.Title) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Title", "*") %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Director">Director:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("Director", Model.Director) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Director", "*") %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="DateReleased">DateReleased:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("DateReleased", String.Format("{0:g}", Model.DateReleased)) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("DateReleased", "*") %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Presumably when you hit save it will construct the movieToEdit based on the textboxes on the page automatically. But Id isn't one of the fields on the page, so how does it know what it is? Does it create hidden fields for properties such as Id automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID is most likely in your URL since default MVC route definition is:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Your `<form>` in the view most likely posts back to something like:

```
http://www.yourappaddress.com/movies/edit/N
```

where N is movie ID. All other movie property values are sent via form POST values.

Comment: That would make sense, but how does it know that the ID property of the model maps to the id in the Url? You could have a movie.id, movie.theatreid, movie.somethingid and it'd need to know which one was the primary key

Comment: @SLC: because your `Movie` class has property `Id` which gets automatically bound to your action method parameter. Whenever you'd supply `Id` inside a hidden field that is a different thing. MVC code should be checked which one takes precedence. Or test it yourself. Add a `<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => 100) %>` and see wheter your `movieToEdit` will have correct `Id` or will it be 100... You could do the same test by providing `Id` as URL query string parameter `?Id=200` in your URL.

Comment: @SLC, more specifically because you made a movie your *model*, and now the model has an ID property (casing doesn't matter).

Comment: @SLC: If your `Movie` class would have property called `MovideId` this abutmatic model binding from URL to property wouldn't happen. But keep it as it is now, because this model binding is a good thing.